# Remove previous DOM elements when using array map method

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pokeapi

I'm trying to implement server side pagination with NodeJS/Express. But the frontend rendering of it isn't working as expected. I fetch from a third-party API and implement the logic for the pagination. I then connect it to the frontend for rendering.

I have created cards to render the information from the API, first time remove the cards to render next page elements/cards with the code:

```
if(card !== undefined){
    card.remove();
}
```

It works and it removes the cards, you can see this in the frontend, first eventlistener. But when I try to implement the same in the second eventlistener the elements/cards aren't removed and replaced with new ones.

**Pagination - Backend**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

router.get('/pokemon', function(req, res) {

    async function getPokemonInfo(){
        return fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=251')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            getDetailsPokemon(data)
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })
    }
    getPokemonInfo()

    async function getDetailsPokemon(pokemon){
        const pokemonArr = pokemon.results;
        const eachPokemon = pokemonArr.map(pokeEl => {
            return fetch(pokeEl.url)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            })

        })
        Promise.all(eachPokemon)
        .then(values => {
            const page = parseInt(req.query.page);
            const limit = parseInt(req.query.limit);
            console.log(page, limit);

            
            const startIndex = (page - 1) * limit;
            const endIndex = page * limit; 
            console.log(startIndex, endIndex);

            const results = {}

            if(endIndex < values.length){
                results.next = {
                    page: page + 1,
                    limit: limit
                }
            }

            if(startIndex > 0){
                results.previous = {
                    page: page - 1,
                    limit: limit
                }
            }

            results.result = values.slice(startIndex, endIndex);
            console.log(results);
            res.json(results)
        })
    }
})

module.exports = router;
```

**Pagination - Frontend**

```
const paginatedApp = {
    paginatedPokemon: async function(){
        await fetch(`http://localhost:1337/pokemon?page=1&limit=20`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            this.createCards(data)
        })
    },

    createCards: function(pokemonObj){
        let next = document.querySelector('.next');
        let previous = document.querySelector('.previous');

        pokemonObj.result.map(pokeEl => {
        // Variables
        let main = document.querySelector('main');
        let card = document.createElement('div');
        let imgHolder = document.createElement('div');
        let img = document.createElement('img');
        let infoHolder = document.createElement('div');
        let infoBoxOne = document.createElement('div');
        let infoBoxTwo = document.createElement('div');
        let pId = document.createElement('p');
        let pName = document.createElement('p');
        let boxForType = document.createElement('div');

        let id = document.createTextNode('id:');
        let name = document.createTextNode('name:');
        let type = document.createTextNode('type:');

        // Info box 1
        let infoPId = document.createElement('p');
        let infoPName = document.createElement('p');
        let infoPType = document.createElement('p');

        infoPId.append(id);
        infoPName.append(name);
        infoPType.append(type);

        infoBoxOne.append(infoPId, infoPName, infoPType);
        infoBoxTwo.append(pId, pName, boxForType);

        // Lägg till klasser
        card.classList.add('card');
        imgHolder.classList.add('imgHolder');

        infoHolder.classList.add('infoHolder');

        boxForType.classList.add('boxForType');

        img.classList.add('img');
        infoHolder.classList.add('infoHolder');
        pId.classList.add('id');
        pName.classList.add('name');
        infoBoxOne.classList.add('infoBoxOne');
        infoBoxTwo.classList.add('infoBoxTwo');

        img.src = pokeEl.sprites.other['official-artwork']['front_default'];
        pId.append(`#${pokeEl.id}`);
        pName.append(pokeEl.name);

        // Types
        pokeEl.types.map(pokeType => {
            let pokemonType = pokeType.type.name
            let pokes = document.createElement('p');
            pokes.append(pokemonType)
            boxForType.append(pokes);
        })

        
        imgHolder.appendChild(img);
        card.appendChild(imgHolder)
        main.appendChild(card);

        infoHolder.append(infoBoxOne)
        infoHolder.append(infoBoxTwo)
        card.appendChild(infoHolder);


        boxForType.children[0].style.border = '1px solid #fff';
        boxForType.children[1] ?  boxForType.children[1].style.border = '1px solid #fff' : console.log('boxForType.children[1] dosen\'t exist for this post');

        next.addEventListener('click', () => {
            if(card !== undefined){
                card.remove();
            }
        })
    })
        // Second next eventlistener
        next.addEventListener('click', () => {
            fetch(`http://localhost:1337/pokemon?page=${pokemonObj.next.page++}&limit=20`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                data.result.map(dataEl => {
                    let main = document.querySelector('main');
                    let card = document.createElement('div');
                    if(card !== undefined){
                        card.remove();
                    }

                    let imgHolder = document.createElement('div');
                    let img = document.createElement('img');
                    let infoHolder = document.createElement('div');
                    let infoBoxOne = document.createElement('div');
                    let infoBoxTwo = document.createElement('div');
                    let pId = document.createElement('p');
                    let pName = document.createElement('p');
                    let boxForType = document.createElement('div');
            
                    let id = document.createTextNode('id:');
                    let name = document.createTextNode('name:');
                    let type = document.createTextNode('type:');
            
                    // Info box 1
                    let infoPId = document.createElement('p');
                    let infoPName = document.createElement('p');
                    let infoPType = document.createElement('p');
            
                    infoPId.append(id);
                    infoPName.append(name);
                    infoPType.append(type);
            
                    infoBoxOne.append(infoPId, infoPName, infoPType);
                    infoBoxTwo.append(pId, pName, boxForType);
            
                    // Lägg till klasser
                    card.classList.add('card');
                    imgHolder.classList.add('imgHolder');
            
                    infoHolder.classList.add('infoHolder');
            
                    boxForType.classList.add('boxForType');
            
                    img.classList.add('img');
                    infoHolder.classList.add('infoHolder');
                    pId.classList.add('id');
                    pName.classList.add('name');
                    infoBoxOne.classList.add('infoBoxOne');
                    infoBoxTwo.classList.add('infoBoxTwo');
            
                    img.src = dataEl.sprites.other['official-artwork']['front_default'];
                    pId.append(`#${dataEl.id}`);
                    pName.append(dataEl.name);
            
                    // Types
                    dataEl.types.map(pokeType => {
                        let pokemonType = pokeType.type.name
                        let pokes = document.createElement('p');
                        pokes.append(pokemonType)
                        boxForType.append(pokes);
                    })
            
                    
                    imgHolder.appendChild(img);
                    card.appendChild(imgHolder)
                    main.appendChild(card);
            
                    infoHolder.append(infoBoxOne)
                    infoHolder.append(infoBoxTwo)
                    card.appendChild(infoHolder);

                    if(card !== undefined){
                        card.remove();
                    }

                })
            })
            
        })
    }
}

paginatedApp.paginatedPokemon();
```